# Formatar layout para impressão em impressora Zebra

Tags: java, android, impressão, impressora

Eu consegui imprimir em uma impressora RW 420 da Zebra, porém não sei como formatar os textos, olhei a documentação para enviar os dados a impressora e notei o seguinte:

```
                String cpclData = "! 0 200 200 210 1\r\n"
                        + "TEXT 4 0 30 40 This is a CPCL test.\r\n"
                        + "FORM\r\n"
                        + "PRINT\r\n";
```

Esse pequeno trecho deixa o texto maior, fonte diferente e em negrito, pretendia somente deixar uma margem do texto no lado esquerdo e direito, pois está muito na margem, e se possível, mudar a fonte e quebrar uma linha, tipo, dividir bem um paragrafo.

Outra coisa que notei, a impressão não aceita caracteres especiais, tipo Ç Â Ã e etc, parece ser ASC, estou correto?

Usei o ZebraDesigner2 e fiz o procedimento para pegar este Script e fiz minha adaptação:

O DEFAULT:

```
! 0 200 200 406 1
PW 609
TONE 0
SPEED 3
ON-FEED IGNORE
NO-PACE
BAR-SENSE
PCX 40 102 
T 5 0 40 301 Negrito
T 5 0 40 240 Negrito
T 2 0 39 331 AUXILIAR 01
T 2 0 39 331 AUXILIAR 02
T 2 0 39 331 AUXILIAR 03
T 2 0 39 331 AUXILIAR 04
T 5 0 40 271 Negrito
T 5 0 40 62 Negrito
T 5 0 40 210 Negrito
T 5 0 40 32 Negrito
PRINT
```

E com minha formatação:

```
                String texto = "! 0 200 200 406 1\r\n"
                        + "PW 609\r\n"
                        + "TONE 0\r\n"
                        + "SPEED 3\r\n"
                        + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n"
                        + "NO-PACE\r\n"
                        + "BAR-SENSE\r\n"
                        + "PCX 40 102\r\n"
                        + "T 5 0 40 301 " + notificacaoText.get(0) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "T 5 0 40 240 " + notificacaoText.get(1) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "T 2 0 39 331 " + notificacaoText.get(2) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "T 2 0 39 331 " + notificacaoText.get(3) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "T 2 0 39 331 " + notificacaoText.get(4) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "T 2 0 39 331 " + notificacaoText.get(5) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "T 2 0 39 331 " + notificacaoText.get(6) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "T 2 0 39 331 " + notificacaoText.get(7) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "T 5 0 40 271 " + notificacaoText.get(8) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "T 5 0 40 62 " + notificacaoText.get(9) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "T 5 0 40 210 " + notificacaoText.get(10) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "T 5 0 40 32 " + notificacaoText.get(11) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "PRINT\r\n";
```

Porém aparece o seguinte erro ao tentar imprimir:

```
  Could not find class 'com.zebra.sdk.util.internal.StringUtilities$1', referenced from method com.zebra.sdk.util.internal.StringUtilities.convertKeyValueJsonToMap
```

Comment: O problema dos caracteres especiais você pode resolver fazendo o upload de uma fonte que os suporte, acho que tem um software da própria zebra que faz isso, deve ser algo tipo "Font Uploader" ou "Font Manager". Sobre o Zebra Designer, por que ele não resolve seu problema?

Comment: Baixei ontem, e pelo que notei tenho que formatar o texto lá no software, porém eu tenho uma String muito grande, não conseguiria ver por lá, posso está enganado, OBS: A impressão é dinâmica, o texto pode mudar.

Comment: Faça o seguinte, molde uma etiqueta através desse Zebra Designer, daí na hora de imprimir escolha "Imprimir para arquivo" ao invés de mandar para a impressora, assim você terá um template da sua etiqueta, você joga ele no seu código edita da forma que bem entender.

Comment: Opa! Desconhecia o "Imprimir para arquivo", vou fazer meus teste a passo o retorno!

Comment: Fiz este procedimento, até funciona, porém, mesmo formatando, é como se ele imprimisse tudo na mesma linha, muito esquisito.

Comment: Resolvido, queria imprimir um paragrafo na linha, mas essas impressoras não interpretam dessa maneira, precisam ser formatadas por cada linha...

Comment: @Vinithius como você conseguiu esse código através do ZebraDesigner2?  Estou no mesmo dilema do layout como você estava mas no meu caso é com uma imagem; tenho que imprimir um bitmap gerado. Voltando, posso ajustar o layout no ZebraDesigner e passá-lo para c#?

Comment: @kaamis com imagem eu ainda estou sofrendo um pouco, porém existe um metodo no Java que imprimi imagens, eu faço assim, primeiro mando o comando de imprimir a imagem e depois o texto, mas nem sempre sai do jeito que eu quero. Agora o código eu consegui gerando o arquivo no ZebraDesigner2 e depois abo no NotePad++, mais tarde mando o código da imagem.

Comment: @Vinithius pesquisei mais um pouco e consegui pegar esse código gerado a partir do ZebraDesigner2. Fiz pelo imprimir como arquivo e deu certo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido... só mudar para dessa forma:

```
                String texto = "! 0 200 200 406 1\r\n"
                        + "TEXT 5 0 40 301 " + notificacaoText.get(0) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "TEXT 5 0 40 240 " + notificacaoText.get(1) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "TEXT 2 0 39 331 " + notificacaoText.get(2) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "TEXT 2 0 39 332 " + notificacaoText.get(3) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "TEXT 2 0 39 333 " + notificacaoText.get(4) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "TEXT 2 0 39 334 " + notificacaoText.get(5) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "TEXT 2 0 39 335 " + notificacaoText.get(6) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "TEXT 2 0 39 336 " + notificacaoText.get(7) +"\r\n" //AUXILIAR
                        + "TEXT 5 0 40 271 " + notificacaoText.get(8) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "TEXT 5 0 40 62 " + notificacaoText.get(9) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "TEXT 5 0 40 210 " + notificacaoText.get(10) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "TEXT 5 0 40 32 " + notificacaoText.get(11) +"\r\n" //Negrito
                        + "FORM\r\n"
                        + "PRINT\r\n";
```

Porém, cada linha tem que ser formatada para o papel, não pode ultrapassar, por exemplo, os 103mm da folha q estou usando, no ZebraDesigner ele mostra o texto em vermelho quando ultrapasso essa margem, cada TEXT é uma linha, se eu colocar um paragrafo no lugar de uma linha bem definida, terei problemas...