# Impressão de conteúdo de picturebox c# em impressora térmica (zebra) por conexão serial

Tags: c#, impressão

Recebi um pedido no trabalho para fazer a impressão de códigos de barras na impressora que tem aqui (*Zebra QL320 plus 1*). O primeiro passo está feito, consegui adaptar um código para gerar o código de barras; este é inserido em uma `pictureBox`. A minha grande dúvida e obstáculo é como vou mandar essa imagem via porta serial para ser impressa? E como consigo ajustar o *layout* da impressão para imprimir duas cópias do código de barras uma ao lado da outra e uma terceira cópia logo após, no tamanho que tenho da etiqueta. Encontrei essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62905/formatar-layout-para-impress%C3%A3o-em-impressora-zebra) aqui do site mas está sendo usada uma `string`, ou seja, será impresso texto e no meu caso é uma imagem `bitmap`. É possível fazer isso? Vi também sobre o *layout* que ele usou o *ZebraDesigner2* para ajustar, acabei de baixar e vou testar. Sou inciante na área e é meu primeiro emprego então está bem difícil nessa parte, nunca programei algo que tenha conexão com alguma coisa, seja ela serial, bluetooh, usb, etc e mexi pouquíssimo com C#. Desde já agradecida!

Comment: Essa imagem foi gerada a partir de uma numeração? Caso positivo pode usa-ló para enviar a impressão. Trabalhei pouco com estas impressoras, sei que elas tem uma linguagem própria. No seu caso você não vai enviar a imagem e sim o `código de barras (número)` a impressora se encarrega de "desenhar" o código.

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html

Comment: Sim. O programa ainda vai ser aperfeiçoado para buscar os códigos únicos de uns componentes, porém, por enquanto o usuário tem que digitar. Mas sim, é a partir de uma numeração.